# Alternatie style in place of margin for html email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, margin

How can I use something in place of :

```
margin-top: -40px;
```

For and HTML email ?

It works fine in Webmails but not in Outlook !

I test it on different version of Outlook and got always the same result !

> *I need this to put a part of second table which is text on the bottom of the first table which is an image !

Update :

**I managed to resolve this problem by doing some graphic design, but looking forward for any answer that could resolve the problem using CSS.**

Answer (score 0):

outlook doesn't support negative values , even sometimes margin also. so instead of `margin` use `padding` in `tr/td` and you can try to write `Margin:-40px;` instead of `margin:-40px;` . keep **m** as Capital.

Hope it may solve your problem.

you can check here for standard rules for making HTML Emailer.

[HTML Email Guideline](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Thx for the link :)